# Spring Service implementing multiple interfaces: good or bad?

Tags: java, spring, service

Is it a bad practice to have a Spring Service break down its functionality by implementing multiple interfaces and then having Spring inject that one Service instance using the interface that declares only the required methods where needed?

Like:

```java
public interface OperationsService1 {

    public void operation1();

    public void operation2();

}


public interface OperationsService2 {

    public void operation3();

    public void operation4();

}

@Service
public class OperationsServiceImpl implements OperationsService1, OperationsService2 {

    public void operation1() {}

    public void operation2() {}

    public void operation3() {}

    public void operation4() {}

}
```

and then in the calling class:

```java
@Autowire
private OperationsService1 ops1;
```

or

```java
@Autowire
private OperationsService2 ops2;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more a matter of design than a matter of Spring from my point of view. Generally, a class should be responsible for a single functionality (see [SRP on wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)). So one service class should implement one service interface.

Answer (score 0):

> and then having Spring inject the Service instance using the interface
>   that declares only the required methods where needed?

First of all I feel like you are confused. In your example there won't be an instance for each interface. When you call

```
@Autowire
private OperationsService1 ops1;

@Autowire
private OperationsService2 ops2;
```

they will both point to the same OperationsServiceImpl class because the bean is singleton by default. What you have here is one instace and two interfaces which point to it. By autowiring the interfaces it means that for the first interface you can call only some of the methods in the bean, with the 2nd interface some other methods of the same bean.

> It it a good practice?

I don't think so, usually one would use an interface with multiple object instances with various functionality which is not the case here as explained above. It's gonna get even more messy if other classes start implementing these interfaces and you have to use @Qualifier to distinguish between them. If you want a clean solution separate the OperationsServiceImpl into two separate classes and each of them implement the corresponding interface. It would be less complex and easier to support for new developers.

Comment: Also to add @george's point , it seems like it is also violating Single Responsibilty Principle. you can interfaces when you are implementing polymorphic behavior. So you should separate 2 classes with each class implementing single interface . This will be make your code clean..

Comment: @george, the first part I was aware of, maybe I didn't make myself clear. I was just asking if it's a bad practice to expose parts of the whole functionality through different interfaces and use them accordingly as needed.